# Where to process/sanitize database input in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I think the title does cover the question, but i'll explain the question anyway.

Say I have a user that submits a comment, and in that comment he was allowed to use Markdown.
Now I want to parse the comment on the server for Markdown and transform the Markdown syntax into HTML, but strip out any html or other unwanted syntax and then save it in the DB. Where should I do this? Should I do this in the controller or during the validation of the model?

An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this generally outside of the controller passing it off to a class to sanitize the data. If you just want to sanitize passed in HTML you can use the antixss library's Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment()

If you want the rules displayed to the user pm validation then you could consider implementing IValidateableObject in your model but I still wouldnt actually do the filtering here.

Comment: Yes, I knew about passing it off to a separate class, but I just wanted to know where in the MVC logic I should do this. Reading your answer I guess its the controller.

Comment: ya I wouldn't do this in the model itself. You could have this method in the POCO object you map your view model to (if you are using view models) but just ensure there is no persistence logic in your poco itself.